# Writing "the sum of two odd integers is even" in symbolic notation

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

How do I represent this statement using symbolic notation?

This is my attempt at it.
$$
\forall n \in \Bbb{Z}, \forall m \in \Bbb{Z}, (n = 2q + 1) \wedge (m = 2k + 1) \Longrightarrow (m + n = 2l)
$$

In English, I would read it as:

> For all $n$ in the set of integers, and for all $m$ in the set of integers, if $n$ is odd and $m$ is odd, then $m + n$ is even.

Is this the right way to show it symbolically?

Comment: yup, that works, if you construct L = q + k + 1. You should also state the existence of such integers q and k (for all n, there exists a q such that n = 2q+1 etc.)

Comment: The formula is : $\forall n \forall m  [\exists q \exists k (n = 2q +1 \land m = 2k +1) \rightarrow \exists l (m+n = 2l) ]$, where all variables are "restricted" to the domain $\mathbb Z$, and your reading is right.

Answer (score 2):

Rather:
$$
\forall n \in \Bbb{Z}, \forall m \in \Bbb{Z} 
\Big(\big(\exists q\in\mathbb Z (n = 2q + 1)\big) \wedge \big(\exists k\in\mathbb Z(m = 2k + 1)\big)
\Longrightarrow \exists \ell\in\mathbb Z(m + n = 2\ell)\Big)
$$
Note. Final version improved according to the suggestions of Henning Makholm.

Comment: @drhab: Thanks.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Fixed.

Comment: x @Yiorgios: Perhaps I was unclear. Instead of $\exists q\in\mathbb Z,\exists k\in\mathbb Z\big((n = 2q + 1) \wedge (m = 2k + 1)\big)$ I would write $\big(\exists q\in\mathbb Z (n = 2q + 1)\big) \wedge \big(\exists k\in\mathbb Z(m = 2k + 1)\big)$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Thanks. Done it.