# Is my quantified statement correct?

Tags: quantifiers

Every even integer can be expressed as the sum of two odd integers:

This is my try for the statement a=b+c

$\small(\forall a{\in}\Bbb Z)(\forall b{\in}Z)(\forall c{\in}\Bbb Z)\big[{[( \exists x{\in}\Bbb Z)(a=2x)\wedge(\exists y{\in}\Bbb Z)(b=2y+1)\wedge(\exists z{\in}\Bbb Z)(a=2z+1)]\to[a=b+c]}\big]$

Reference is taken through:

[the sum of two odd integers is even](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/693100/the-sum-of-two-odd-integers-is-even)

Comment: It must be : "for every $a$ (if $a$ is Even, then there are $b,c$ such that $b$ is Odd and $c$ is Odd and $a=b+c$)".

Comment: ∀a∈Z [∃x∈Z (a=2x)⟹[∃b∈Z ∃c∈Z (∃y∈Z)(b=2y+1) ^ (∃z∈Z)(c=2z+1) ^ (a=b+c)]]

Thankyou!!